# How can i upload an image through react native(expo) to azure blob storage? (get real time image and upload that image)

Tags: react-native, azure-blob-storage, image-upload

Through form data i'm able to upload the image to azure blob storage through backend. How can i get real time image from expo camera and upload the same to azure blob storage.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8XSA.png)

Backend code-  flask python

```
@app.route('/api/addincident', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():  # to upload image
    file = request.files['file']
    damage_type = request.form.get('damage_type')
    damage_parts = request.form.get('damage_parts')
    location_address = request.form.get('location_address')
    geolocation_latitude = request.form.get('geolocation_latitude')
    geolocation_longitude = request.form.get('geolocation_latitude')
    datetime = request.form.get('datetime')
    created_by = request.form.get('created_by')
    created_on = request.form.get('created_on')
    modified_by = request.form.get('modified_by')
    modified_on = request.form.get('modified_on')
    customer_id = request.form.get('customer_id')

    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    fileextension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
    Randomfilename = id_generator()
    filename = Randomfilename + '.' + fileextension
    try:
        blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(container, filename, file)
    except Exception:
        print('Exception=' + Exception)
        pass
    image_filepath = 'http://' + account + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + container + '/' + filename

    connection = database
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO incidentreport(damage_type, damage_parts, location_address, 
                        geolocation_latitude, geolocation_longitude, datetime, image_filepath, created_by, created_on, modified_by, 
                        modified_on, customer_id)VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """

    cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, (
        damage_type, damage_parts, location_address, geolocation_latitude, geolocation_longitude, datetime,
        image_filepath, created_by, created_on, modified_by, modified_on, customer_id))

    connection.commit()

    return image_filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use camera control through Power Apps and upload the images to Azure Blob Storage.
There is a property called Stream (Use the Stream, StreamRate, and OnStream properties to automatically capture images on a timer, for example snapping a picture every minute to create a time-lapse sequence.) on the [Camera control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-camera)

[How to upload images from the camera control to Azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-camera)